# .Net 6 - which C# SignalR client/server packages?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

Can someone tell me what NuGet package(s) I should be using for a .Net 6 C# SignalR Hub project and a .Net 6 C# SignalR client project?

On the client project, I tried:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="6.0.14" />
```

Which seemed to work fine.  It's a .Net 6 project, so I assumed I should be using the latest 6.x.x package.  Is this correct?  So which 'matching' package should I be using on the server side project?  There's a lot of junk in NuGet of deprecated packages (V1.10, 2.4.2) and versions that make no sense.

There's several different threads of documentation on the MS website that has contradictory information on it.  (So yes, I did try and research this...)

There was a 'popular' version of server-side version 2.4.3,

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" Version="2.4.3" />
```

but I got warnings saying it 'might' not be compatible with .Net 6.  It appeared to work, but not sure it's best practice matching up these unlikely versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you want version 6 to go with NetCore 6. I feel this is not obvious. You can verify it by comparing the framework version highlighted at

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/6.0.14#supportedframeworks-body-tab

With the next version up:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/7.0.3#supportedframeworks-body-tab

and see that SignalR.Client version 6 supports net6, whereas Client version 7 supports net7.

(And, on the dependencies tab, you can see that version 7 will drag in AspNet 7 dependencies)

**Serverside**

There is no serverside package because it is included in AspNetCore, per the top-right box in the first table on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Seems like I should just take out any explicit PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.  And voila!  It compiles.  Thanks!!!